# Reading information from Memory array into excel sheet formula

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, memory, formula

I'd like to use data from an array that I've got stored in my VBA memory directly into a formula in my sheet. As an example, I'd like to avoid using Application.vlookup() to print to each cell individually as this is slow. And instead do something like the following

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim MyArrayStoredInVBaMemory() As Variant
    MyArrayStoredInVBaMemory = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
    Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC1,MyArrayStoredInVBaMemory,1,0)"
    Cells(1, 2).Copy
    Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if you can do it this way. Would normally check by my PC is being overloaded with a huge countif at the moment. But first thing to do would be the change "Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC1,MyArrayStoredInVBaMemory,1,0)"" To "Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC1," & MyArrayStoredInVBaMemory& ",1,0)""

Comment: What are the formulas you intent to use data directly into? Assigning array to the cells value might be handy as it works fast: `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 9)).Value = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`, and then you can link your formula arguments to these cells.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make a *String* from the *Array*

```
Sub qwerty()
    ary = Array(1, 2, 3)
    Dim st As String
    st = ary(0) & "," & ary(1) & "," & ary(2)
    Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" & st & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: +1, but I'd skip the string-building and use Join instead: `Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Join(ary, ",") & ")"`